# Hangfire Dashboard - Blank on Azure VM

Tags: c#, asp.net, hangfire

I've got an ASP.NET WEB Running on an Azure VM and its using Hangfire.IO for background jobs.

When running this on my development machine the Dashboard for Hangfire works fine.

When i deploy to the VM the dashboard is just a white screen.

I know that by default the Dashboard will only work locally and not remotely.

However, I'm trying to access the Dashboard whilst logged onto the server in which its hosted, and i still get a blank screen.

The Hangfire service itself is working fine, its only the Dashboard that is the issue.

I've seen a few different examples of workarounds where ppl are applying Authorization filters, but i dont think that applies in this instance.. as i only wish to access the dashboard from the VM that its hosted on and not "remotely".